# Kotlin maven plugin ignores jvmTarget

Tags: kotlin

**Spring Boot:** 3.2.0, **Kotlin:** 1.9.21, **Build Image:** maven:3.9.5-amazoncorretto-21, **Run Image:** amazoncorretto:17

I have a very simple Spring Boot project

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)

    listOf(1,2,3,4).removeLast()
}
```

The pom look like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.21</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>${java.version}</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Notice the `<jvmTarget>${java.version}</jvmTarget>` in the Kotlin plugin configuration which is pointing to Java 17.

```
FROM maven:3.9.5-amazoncorretto-21 AS builder

RUN mkdir "/app"

WORKDIR /app

COPY src ./src
COPY pom.xml .

RUN mvn clean package

FROM amazoncorretto:17

COPY --from=builder /app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Now, if I build and run this

```bash
docker build -t demo .
```

```bash
docker run demo
```

I get the following exception:

```kotlin
INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt       : Starting DemoApplicationKt v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.9 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.removeLast()'
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt.main(DemoApplication.kt:12)
```

If you check the docs related to `removeLast()` it is available version **21**

> Removes and returns the last element of this collection (optional operation).
> Throws:
> NoSuchElementException – if this collection is empty
> UnsupportedOperationException – if this collection implementation does not support this   operation
> Implementation Requirements:
> If this List is not empty, the implementation in this interface returns the result of  calling remove(size() - 1). Otherwise, it throws NoSuchElementException.
> Since:21

Apparently, Kotlin plugin ignores `<jvmTarget>` configuration. If I change the build image to `maven:3.9.5-amazoncorretto-17` the problem will go away.

Is this a bug in Kotlin's plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. Its explained in [KT-64593 Kotlin maven plugin ignores jvmTarget](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-64593/Kotlin-maven-plugin-ignores-jvmTarget#focus=Comments-27-8760324.0-0).

I missed adding a compiler argument -Xjdk-release=17.

[-Xjdk-release](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#xjdk-release-version) in Kotlin is similar to **--release** [JEP 247](https://openjdk.org/jeps/247).

In my case I only set `jvmTarget` this is equivalent to

```bash
javac --target 17
```

in Java.

Note that in the above I have not specified [--source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-source). The default behaviour is, if missing, default to current Java SE release (the one you are using).